# How to label outputs from Print

Tags: expression-manipulation, core-language

I have problem with `Print` in *Mathematica*. The data that I get from it, is not labelled so that I can use it elsewhere, therefore I have got to label them manually. This is a very burdensome task and I am looking for a efficient way to overcome this. Allow me to elucidate this: my code has the following form:

```
Do[Print[Evaluate[ψ[x, 7] /. First[sol]]], {x, -1, 1, 0.01}]
```

the data that I get from this code are numbers and I have to label them, which is a lot of numbers to label.

Is there any other way to print this numbers with labels so that I can use them later or any additional commands to put inside `Print`? 
I hope my question was clear, if not I can be more specific.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "labelling", and how it is related to using the result in other commands. Can you give an example?

Comment: yes, sure. For example, the output of Print Command gives me number like  0.0001, 0.000032, 0.00000043,0.00000234 and so on ( up to 1000 data outputs) which is not labelled like p1:=0.0001, p2:= 0.000032, p3:= 0.00000043, p4:= 0.00000234 etc. I want to have a appointed labels or something like that to use those numbers elsewhere. Is there any option for this?

Comment: `p = Table[Evaluate[ψ[x, 7] /. First[sol]], {x, -1, 1, 0.01}]`? Then access the elements using `Part`, e.g. `p[[1]]`

Comment: Dear Marius  This is much more better. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest not using `Print` at all. `Print` is mainly a debugging tool in *Mathematica*. Next, assuming that by labeling you mean putting the set of numbers generated by an iteration into a structure that you can retrieve them from later, here are two approaches.

I build a table of values of `Sin[x]` with `x` going from 0 to 90 degrees in 10 degree increments as my example. I can't use your example because it leaves too many things undefined.

Make an association.

```
Clear[sn];
sn = Association [Table[i -> N[Sin[i Degree]], {i, 0, 90 , 10 }]];
```

Make a sequence of indexed assignments.

```
Clear[sn];
Do[sn[i] = N[Sin[i Degree]], {i, 0, 90 , 10 }]
```

In either case, you would reference a value in the same way. For example, to retrieve the sine of 30°, you would write

```
sn[30]
```

> `0.5`

Although the reference expressions are identical, the storage structure in each case is quite different. To learn about these structures look up [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) and [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) in the Documentation Center.

Comment: very complete and useful thank you